# CSOM Copy List Items

Tags: javascript, csom

I was create Ribbon Custom Action, and try to copy list items selected to same list, but F12 error? what is the problem?

[image]

```
function runCode() {
    var targetListItem;
    var values = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
    var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
    targetListItem = targetList.getItemById(values[0].id);
    clientContext.load(targetListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        var oListItem = targetList.addItem(itemCreateInfo); 
        oListItem.set_item('Title', targetListItem.get_item('Title'));  
        oListItem.update();
        clientContext.load(oListItem); 
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
            SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Item created!', false);
            SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
       },Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

   },Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
   }

   function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
```

Error:

> Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: The value cannot be null. Parameter
>   name: method

Comment: Are you trying to copy items is same list??

Comment: Hello Ganesh Sanap, yes ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrote the code:

```
function getSelectedItems(OnSuccess, OnError) {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
    var selectedItemIds = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
    var listItems = [];
    for (idx in selectedItemIds) {
        var item = list.getItemById(parseInt(selectedItemIds[idx].id));
        listItems.push(item);
        context.load(item);
    }
    context.executeQueryAsync(
       function () {
           OnSuccess(listItems);
       },
       OnError
    );
}
function copy() {
 var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
    var ListGUID = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getById(ListGUID);
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    getSelectedItems(function (items) {
        for (var i = 0 ; i < items.length; i++) {
        var oListItem = targetList.addItem(itemCreateInfo); 
        oListItem.set_item('Title', items[i].get_item('Title'));
        oListItem.update();
        clientContext.load(oListItem); 
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync();
        }
    },
        function (sender, args) {
            alert('An error occured: ' + args.get_message());
        });
    }
```

Comment: What was the exact issue causing error??

Comment: For some reason, the values of the selected items were null. Rewrote code differently.

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code:

```
var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
clientContext.load(targetList);
targetListItem = targetList.getItemById(values[0].id);
clientContext.load(targetListItem, 'Title');
```

**Reference**:

1. [SP.List.getItemById Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj246019(v=office.15))

Comment: did not help ((

Comment: Are you getting same error?

Comment: Try this updated answer? are you getting anything in targetList??